# How can we make a user sign up another user using Firebase/Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I know it's possible to sign up a user with email and password with the following code:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password;)
```

That works fine. I can also add documents and collections in Firestore as such:

```
Future<void> getUserDoc() {
  // Initiate an auth instance
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  // Initiate a firebase firestore instance
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  // Create a current user object
  User user = _auth.currentUser!;
  // Create a document reference based on the 'users'
  DocumentReference ref = _firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid);

  // Return a collection that sets/updates the following data
  // based on the user.uid
  return ref.set({
    'UID': user.uid,
    'Email': user.email,
    'CreatedUserAt': user.metadata.creationTime,
    'LastSignInAt': user.metadata.lastSignInTime,
    'EmailVerified': user.emailVerified,
  });
}
```

What I need is that the user that is signed in now - for example a business, can sign up their clients. Their clients will receive a link in their email to confirm and then they are signed up to the platform. However, the tricky part is that those clients should be added to the business that signed them up through the business account when they log in. I'm really stuck with this part of how this logic would work in Firestore.

Comment: Can you please explain " those friends should be added to the user that signed them up through his account when he was logged in." ? Also ff you create new account using Firebase client SDKs then existing user will get logged out. You'll have to use Admin SDK in that case.

Comment: I changed it now, instead of friends I used a business - client relationship. Maybe that is clearer?

Comment: Yes, much clear now.

Comment: Cool, thank you Dharmaraj for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, users with business account can invite client via an email and when the client signs up using the link, you need to add that client under this business. You can use a Cloud functions to invite a client along with business account ID of inviter as shown below:

```
exports.inviteClient = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // UID of user inviting client (or the business ID)
  const { uid } = context.auth; 

  // Add data in a database that maps user email with business ID
  // When user signs up, you can refer to this data to find who invited user

  // Send email link to sign up user

  return; 
});
```

After user signs up, you can then read ID of business who invited user and add it in users collection. I would recommend running this logic in a Cloud function so no user can change it from client side. Or if you'll use Firestore to store the mapping as well then you can use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) to verify inviter ID.

---

Another approach could be creating a user in `inviteClient` function itself and add a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) containing business ID.

---

If you do not want to use Cloud functions then you can add a user document containing business ID right after someone is invited and use security rules to ensure users cannot change their inviter's ID. However, you'll need a Cloud function/server to generate sign in links for users and send emails.

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj, is this with Flutter? It seems Typescript no?

Comment: @N90J Cloud functions only supports Javascript or Typescript at the moment. I've updated the answer with the same. Let me know if I am missing anything from the use case

Comment: Interesting approaches, I'll take some time to read through the logic and materials and if no one else comes up with a Flutter specific answer (e.g. I saw that there is a firebase_dynamic_links package on pub.dev), then I will mark this one as correct. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @N90J if you create your own links to identify user and businesses then you can remove Cloud functions part totally tbh and try to run everything via security rules. Sending emails however is done from server side mostly. Firebase's [trigger email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email) extention might be useful there.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it! I will read through the stuff these days and let you know ;)